SSH connection key authentication errors
I'm new to C and want to write a program that connects to my vps (ubuntu, apache) and then transfers a folder to it. I have the following problems when trying to authenticate the public keys:
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.534159, 2] ssh_config_parse_line:  Unapplicable option: SendEnv, line: 51
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.534333, 1] ssh_config_parse_line:  Unsupported option: HashKnownHosts, line: 52
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.534503, 2] ssh_connect:  libssh 0.9.6 (c) 2003-2021 Aris Adamantiadis, Andreas Schneider and libssh contributors. Distributed under the LGPL, please refer to COPYING file for information about your rights, using threading threads_pthread
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.534670, 2] ssh_socket_connect:  Nonblocking connection socket: 3
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.534717, 2] ssh_connect:  Socket connecting, now waiting for the callbacks to work
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.558900, 1] socket_callback_connected:  Socket connection callback: 1 (0)
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.590355, 2] ssh_client_connection_callback:  SSH server banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.590388, 2] ssh_analyze_banner:  Analyzing banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.7
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.590402, 2] ssh_analyze_banner:  We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 8.9 (80900)
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.592963, 1] ssh_key_cmp:  key types don't match!
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.593048, 1] ssh_key_cmp:  key types don't match!
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.593059, 1] ssh_key_cmp:  key types don't match!
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.593079, 1] ssh_known_hosts_read_entries:  Failed to open the known_hosts file '/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts': No such file or directory
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.613836, 2] ssh_kex_select_methods:  Negotiated curve25519-sha256,ssh-ed25519,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aead-gcm,aead-gcm,none,none,,
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.688394, 2] ssh_init_rekey_state:  Set rekey after 4294967296 blocks
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.688466, 2] ssh_init_rekey_state:  Set rekey after 4294967296 blocks
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.688524, 2] ssh_packet_newkeys:  Received SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.689244, 2] ssh_packet_newkeys:  Signature verified and valid
Connected to server
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.689486, 1] ssh_key_cmp:  key types don't match!
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.689664, 1] ssh_key_cmp:  key types don't match!
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.689698, 1] ssh_key_cmp:  key types don't match!
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.690957, 1] ssh_agent_get_ident_count:  Answer type: 12, expected answer: 12
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.808627, 1] ssh_packet_userauth_failure:  Access denied for 'publickey'. Authentication that can continue: publickey,password
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.808699, 2] ssh_packet_userauth_failure:  Access denied for 'publickey'. Authentication that can continue: publickey,password
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.808772, 1] ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file:  Error opening /home/intero/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub: No such file or directory
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.808817, 1] ssh_pki_import_privkey_file:  Error opening /home/intero/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.808863, 1] ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file:  Error opening /home/intero/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub: No such file or directory
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.808903, 1] ssh_pki_import_privkey_file:  Error opening /home/intero/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.842444, 1] ssh_packet_userauth_failure:  Access denied for 'publickey'. Authentication that can continue: publickey,password
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.842516, 2] ssh_packet_userauth_failure:  Access denied for 'publickey'. Authentication that can continue: publickey,password
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.842589, 1] ssh_pki_import_pubkey_file:  Error opening /home/intero/.ssh/id_dsa.pub: No such file or directory
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.842634, 1] ssh_pki_import_privkey_file:  Error opening /home/intero/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
[2024/05/12 18:45:12.842668, 2] ssh_userauth_publickey_auto:  Tried every public key, none matched
authenticated

with this code:
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ENV_PATH "../source/"

typedef struct {
  char host[50];
  char username[50];
  int port;
  int verbosity;
} ConnectionInfo;

void read_env(ConnectionInfo *credentials) {
  char env_full_path[50];
  int env_print =
      snprintf(env_full_path, sizeof(env_full_path), "%s.env", ENV_PATH);
  if (env_print < 0) {
    printf("Error printing environment path to environment buffer.\n");
    exit(1);
  };

  FILE *file = fopen(env_full_path, "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening env file.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  char line[50];
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    char *token = strtok(line, "=");
    if (strcmp(token, "HOST") == 0) { // Fixed comparison
      token = strtok(NULL, "=");
      strcpy(credentials->host, token);
      credentials->host[strcspn(credentials->host, "\n")] = '\0';
    } else if (strcmp(token, "USERNAME") == 0) {
      token = strtok(NULL, "=");
      strcpy(credentials->username, token);
      credentials->username[strcspn(credentials->username, "\n")] = '\0';
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
  credentials->verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
  credentials->port = 22;
}

// build folder, vps folder name, reminder that the build folder on vps will be
// replaced if it exists

void prompt_for_info(char *path_variable, char *vps_folder_name) {
  puts("Please remember that the target folder on the vps will be deleted if "
       "it already exists. If this is not desired, please cancel.");
  puts("Enter build path:");
  scanf("%s", path_variable);
  puts("Enter vps folder name:");
  scanf("%s", vps_folder_name);
}

void set_ssh_options(ssh_session session, ConnectionInfo *credentials) {
  ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, &credentials->host);
  ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &credentials->verbosity);
  ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, &credentials->port);
}

int verify_knownhost(ssh_session session) {
  enum ssh_known_hosts_e state;
  state = ssh_session_is_known_server(session);

  switch (state) {
  case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_OK:
    /* OK */

    break;
  case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_CHANGED:
    fprintf(stderr, "Host key for server changed: it is now:\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "For security reasons, connection will be stopped\n");
    return -1;
  case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_OTHER:
    fprintf(stderr, "The host key for this server was not found but an other"
                    "type of key exists.\n");
    fprintf(stderr,
            "An attacker might change the default server key to"
            "confuse your client into thinking the key does not exist\n");

    return -1;
  case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_NOT_FOUND:
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not find known host file.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "If you accept the host key here, the file will be"
                    "automatically created.\n");

    /* FALL THROUGH*/

  case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_UNKNOWN:
    fprintf(stderr, "The server is unknown. Do you trust the host key?\n");
    return -1;
  case SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_ERROR:
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %s", ssh_get_error(session));
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

int authenticate_pubkey(ssh_session session, char *passphrase, char *username) {
  int rc;
  rc = ssh_userauth_publickey_auto(session, username, passphrase);
  if (rc == SSH_AUTH_ERROR) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Authentication failed: %s\n", ssh_get_error(session));
    return SSH_AUTH_ERROR;
  }

  return rc;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  ConnectionInfo server_login;
  int rc;
  enum ssh_known_hosts_e state;
  read_env(&server_login);

  char build_path[250], vps_folder_name[250], passphrase[50];
  prompt_for_info(build_path, vps_folder_name);

  ssh_session ssh_conn = ssh_new();
  if (ssh_conn == NULL) {
    printf("Error creating SSH session.\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  set_ssh_options(ssh_conn, &server_login);
  rc = ssh_connect(ssh_conn);
  if (rc != SSH_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to localhost: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(ssh_conn));
    exit(-1);
  };

  printf("Connected to server\n");
  if (verify_knownhost(ssh_conn) < 0) {
    printf("Problem with verifying known host");
    ssh_disconnect(ssh_conn);
    ssh_free(ssh_conn);
    exit(-1);
  }
  sprintf(passphrase, "passphraseHardcodedForNow");
  rc = authenticate_pubkey(ssh_conn, server_login.username, passphrase);
  if (rc == SSH_AUTH_ERROR) {
    ssh_disconnect(ssh_conn);
    ssh_free(ssh_conn);

    printf("Couldnt authenticate through pubkey");
    exit(-1);
  }
  printf("authenticated\n");
  ssh_disconnect(ssh_conn);
  ssh_free(ssh_conn); 

  return 0;
}

In the .ssh folder on my vps I have the following files:
.   moduli
ssh_config.d
ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub  
ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub  
ssh_host_rsa_key.pub  
sshd_config
ssh_config  
ssh_host_ecdsa_key  
ssh_host_ed25519_key    
ssh_host_rsa_key          
ssh_import_id         
sshd_config.d

with the ssh_config having this content:
# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

on my local computer I have the following files:
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts  known_hosts.old

So I guess the error message that certain files don't exist is accurate.
I created the keys using:

and copied them to the server using:

In the authorized_keys file on my vps there is one key associated with my personal computer so that seems to be right.
The key has a passphrase associated with it.
I have not tried anything yet since I didn't find anything on this on the internet.
